# Oracle regexp - reformat a string to date-like information

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

A column holds the name of a special kind of files, which are named like this: "**kontrolrapport-2015.12.23-10.19.05.pdf**". I want to extract the date, that is "**2015-12-23 10:19**".
I thought it would be peace of cake, but it's takes a little bit more, than I'm able to figure out.
This is how far I get
`select 'kontrolrapport-2015.12.23-10.19.05.pdf' as file_name, 
       regexp_replace('kontrolrapport-2015.12.23-10.19.05.pdf','(\w*)-', '') as date_like
 from dual;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example regex, I'm assuming there is a variable prefix in your file name followed by a hyphen followed by date followed by time and then a file extension.

Here is the regex I used to extract each piece of information -

```
with f as (SELECT 'kontrolrapport-2015.12.23-10.19.05.pdf' AS file_name,
       '([^-]+)-([0-9\.]+)-([0-9\.]+)\.([a-z]+)' AS regex
  FROM DUAL)
select  f.file_name, 
        regexp_substr (f.file_name, f.regex, 1, 1, 'i', 1) as prefix_part,
        regexp_substr (f.file_name, f.regex, 1, 1, 'i', 2) as date_part,
        regexp_substr (f.file_name, f.regex, 1, 1, 'i', 3) as time_part,
        regexp_substr (f.file_name, f.regex, 1, 1, 'i', 4) as file_extension
 from f;
```

Start with this and maybe improve on it further. I'd replace `[a-z]` and `[0-9]` with POSIX classes.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. :-) Even though you use regexp_substr and not - as I thought would be more appropriate - regexp_replace. The next thing for me is to discover, how to use POSIX classes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is predictable, you could do:

```
select to_date(substr('kontrolrapport-2015.12.23-10.19.05.pdf', 16,19), 'YYYY.MM.DD-HH.MI.SS') from dual;
```

or even

```
select to_date(replace(replace('kontrolrapport-2015.12.23-10.19.05.pdf', 'kontrolrapport-',''),'.pdf','') , 'YYYY.MM.DD-HH.MI.SS') from dual;
```

and if you wanted it as a string indicated in your question, how about encompassing either of the above in a to_char such as:

```
select to_char(to_date(substr('kontrolrapport-2015.12.23-10.19.05.pdf', 16,19), 'YYYY.MM.DD-HH.MI.SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI')
```

Comment: I appreciate the substr-simplicity, but as you write: The format might not bee 100% predictable, so I still go for a regexp-solution. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use substr and to_date functions it'easier

To_date(Substr(filename,  13,15),'yyyy.mm.dd-hh24.mi')

would return date

Comment: I like keeping it simple. From that point of view, your suggestion is very usefull. But I'm looking for something that will be robust for minor variatons of the filename, which I think will be a problem with th substr-approach. But thanks for your time!